# Rewriting URL with hyphen not working on GoDaddy

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have this website on my test server, and it works perfectly fine, but when I uploaded it on the GoDaddy server, the rewrite seems to fail.

Here is the concerned part of the .htaccess

```
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$ $1.php

    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/?$ $1.php

    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/([0-9\-]+)$ $1.php?v=$2

    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/([0-9\-]+)/?$ $1.php?v=$2
```

So basically, the URL: **www.site.com/page-one** should open up the page **www.site.com/page-one.php**. But it's not. It throws the following error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /page-one was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying 
to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Any and all help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a domain I could look at for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up coding in independent rules for the individual pages.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the ModRewrite module is activated in the server configuration and that the `AllowOverride` is set to `all`.

Did you activated the RewriteEngine into your `.htaccess` file? You can do that like here:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Comment: Yes it's enabled and I have turned it on in the .htaccess as well. All other rewrites are working, only the ones with hyphens are failing :/